# How should I override Equals and GetHashCode for HashSet?

Tags: c#, hash, equals, hashset

Lets say I Have class:

```
    public class Ident
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String SName { get; set; }
    }
```

and also one more:

```
    class IdenNode
    {
        public Ident id { get; set; }
        public List<IdenNode> Nodes { get; set; }

        public IdenNode()
        {
            Nodes = new List<IdenNode>();
        }
    }
```

I want to use `HashSet<IdenNode>` with mind that two elements of it are same(Equal) if and only if their id.Names are Equal.

So, I'm gonna override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` like next:

```
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            IdenNode otherNode = obj as IdenNode;

            return otherNode != null && 
                   otherNode.id != null && 
                   id.Name == otherNode.id.Name;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            if (id != null)
                return id.Name.GetHashCode();
            else
                // what should I write here?
        }
```

Am I think right? What should I place in `GetHashCode` if so?

**UPDATE**

Could please tell me *is it OK* to use `==` and `!=` in `Equals` method? Or may be `ReferenceEquals` or some other?

Also, should I *override* operators `==` and `!=` ?

Comment: Strings are a terrible thing to use as an identifier, case sensitivity, etc.  Are you not able to use something like an int or a GUID (yes its a string but it's guaranteed unique to your system)

Comment: @Maess makes a good point.  What if two people have the same name and surname?

Comment: @Maess a GUID is not a string! :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice You are correct, I was thinking about databases, where it is sometimes a string.

Comment: You shouldn't override anything. Create the HashSet with an  equality comparer (keep the problem localized). If you do persist, at the very least replace al those `set;` with `private set;`

Answer (score 7):

If `id` (or `id.Name`) is null then it's perfectly fine to return 0.  `Nullable<T>` (like `int?`) returns 0 for "null" values.

Keep in mind that two objects returning the same value from `GetHashCode()` does NOT imply equality - it only implies that two objects *might* be equal.  The flip, however, is that two "equal" objects *must* return the same hash code.  Both principles seem to be fulfilled by your definition of `Equals` and `GetHashCode`

Comment: Got your point about returning 0. Could you tell if I also should override operators "==" and "!="?

Comment: @mehow I should clarify that by "nullable types" I mean `Nullable<T>`.   _Reference_ type don't return _anything_ because you can't call `GetHashCode` on a null reference variable.

Comment: @DStanley perfectly valid answer I just was thinking `ToString()` method on a nullable type. My bad -> +1 to you

Answer (score 5):

Beware of *nulls*! You've got a lot of them. Take care of *StackOverflow*: try *not use* == and != within `Equals` method. Usually, we return **0** as a hash code in case of *null*, e.g.:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj) {
  // Often we should compare an instance with itself, 
  // so let's have a special case for it (optimization)
  if (Object.ReferenceEquals(obj, this)) 
    return true;

  IdenNode other = obj as IdenNode;

  // otherNode != null line in your code can cause StackOverflow:
  // "!=" calls "Equals" which in turn calls "!=" etc...
  if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, other))
    return false;

  // Id can be null
  if (Object.ReferenceEquals(id, other.id))
    return true;
  else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(id, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(other.id, null))
    return false;

  // Let's be exact when comparing strings:
  // i.e. should we use current locale or not etc
  return String.Equals(id.Name, other.id.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal);
}

public override int GetHashCode() {
  // It's typical to return 0 in case of null
  if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, id))
    return 0;
  else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, id.Name)) // <- Name can be null as well!
    return 0;

  return id.Name.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: Wise defensive mechanism +1.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is looks like what I want. Could you tell me if I should override "==" and "!=" in my case?

Comment: @user2706838: You have no need to override them, but, IMHO, you'd better do it

Answer (score 2):

> What should I place in GetHashCode if so?

Returning zero is fine.  Note that defining value equality on a name is a bad idea; I know of at least three other `Eric Lippert`s in the United States and they're not me. There are literally millions, possibly billions, of people who have a name collision.

> Could please tell me is it OK to use "==" and "!=" in Equals method? Or may be ReferenceEquals or some other?

My advice is: when mixing reference and value equality, *be very clear*. If you intend reference equality, say so.

> Also, should I override operators "==" and "!=" ?

Yes. It is confusing to have `Equals` mean one thing and `==` mean another.