# How to make a HashSet<HashSet<int>> work appropriately?

Tags: c#, set, hashset, uniqueidentifier, indices

I have a program where I use an algorithm to determine the 'indices' of an object to determine if it's a unique object, or if it is really holding the same data as another similar object.

The problem is that because of the way this object was created, I can't rely on these indices being in the same order.

For example, an object with indices:

`[0, 1, 2]` is the same as the object as `[0, 2, 1]`.

To handle this problem, I've been putting these indices into a `HashSet<int>`, in the hopes that when I go to compare the sets in the future, it will be easy because in set notation, `{0, 1, 2}` is the same as `{0, 2, 1}`.

The thing is, I can't just go

```
Object1.UniqueHashSet.equals(Object2.UniqueHashSet)
```

because I have A LOT of these objects to compare, and I need to determine how many unique objects I have in a list of these.

To get around this, I've been trying to add these structures into a `HashSet<HashSet<int>>` of themselves, so that in the end I can just return the number of elements in the HashSet.

When I go to add the `HashSet<int>` into the `HashSet<HashSet<int>>` with values `{0, 1, 2}`, and then later add the `HashSet<int>` of `{0, 2, 1}` into the `HashSet<HashSet<int>>` it creates two new elements in the set, when I really only wanted one. So it turns out I have: `{{0, 2, 1}, {0, 1, 2}}`, when I really wanted `{{0, 2, 1}}`.

I've been racking my brain against the wall for hours trying to figure out how to do this. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create an inherited class of HashSet.  You'll want to override the following methods:

```
public override int GetHashCode() { /* Implementation */ }
public override bool Equals(object obj) { /* Implementation */ }
```

The properties will be based on the members of the set.

Then, inserting into the HashSet of the custom class will not lead to duplicates.

You'll have a structure like:

```
HashSet<MyHashSet<int>>
```

The GetHashCode should be a computation based on the individual values in the set.
The Equals should be checking for equals for the members of the set.

Here's some more information on the topic:

[How should I override Equals and GetHashCode for HashSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612678/how-should-i-override-equals-and-gethashcode-for-hashset)

Comment: I've decided to inherit from SortedSet<int>. How can I write a good GetHashCode() and Equals() override such that the complexity isn't O(n) where n is the number of elements in the SortedSet. The complexity is simply too high with my current GetHashCode complexity (It's O(n)) and Equals complexity.

Comment: If they're sorted, you can compare them using [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual(lhs, rhs)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx).